# Can you please explain this formula to me?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, education

I am reading a paper about the spreading of something and the author added a formula to sum it up. My problem is, that I never saw a formula in that way of design. I got what the variables mean, but I do not get how to read that. Is the curly bracket meaning, that it is a group of formulas and the variables on the right are dependencies?

[image]
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a [piecewise function](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/functions-piecewise.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly brackets mean that it is a [piecewise function](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/functions-piecewise.html). Essentially, a piecewise function is a function made out of other functions. You know when to apply each function inside the bracket by looking at the interval provided to the right of each function.

Also, $\exp(x)$ is another way of writing $e^x$

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I learned something new today :)

Comment: @Sylber No problem! You can accept the answer if it was helpful to you by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Yes, I will. Just need to wait 5 min more. One question regarding the t. How is it working when t is a number like 10 and Tstart a number? I mean how is the interval on the right working? Or is it working as a point of time which is compared?

Comment: @Sylber I would assume that $T_{start}$ and $T_{end}$ are constants. So, if $t=10$ and $10 \leq T_{start}$, then you would use the first formula. Moreover, if $t$ is between $T_{start}$ and $T_{end}$, you would use the second formula. Finally, if the value of $t$ is greater than or equal to $T_{end}$, you would use the last formula.